# How to insert an ascii character in a line position?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to edit a list of MACs in `bl:ab:la:bl:ab:la` format >> in to `blab.labl.abla` format. Each MAC is in a line.
I'm new in the use of AWK or SED but I'm almost sure that it can be performed using any of those commands.

Is there any way to set the column position in where a character (a dot) has to be inserted (using sed or awk) in order to accomplish this task?

I've read the sed man page but It didn't get any clear.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example input file along with the output you expect from that example so we can test our solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{print $1$2"."$3$4"."$5$6}'
```

`-F:` will set `:` as the field separator and `print $1$2"."$3$4"."$5$6` will print fields `$1` and `$2` then print a `.` and so on ... the rest is self explanatory.

Example:

```
$ echo "bl:ab:la:bl:ab:la" | awk -F: '{print $1$2"."$3$4"."$5$6}'
blab.labl.abla
```

It can also read from a file like so:

```
awk -F: '{print $1$2"."$3$4"."$5$6}' file
```

and modify the file in-place(*i.e. edit the original file*) like so:

```
gawk -i inplace -F: '{print $1$2"."$3$4"."$5$6}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

If your inputs are actual MAC addresses, then perl has a [Net::MAC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::MAC) module for that (available in Ubuntu via the `libnet-mac-perl` package):

Ex.

```
$ echo '01:23:45:67:89:AB' | perl -MNet::MAC -lne '
    my $m = Net::MAC->new("bit_group" => 8, "delimiter" => ":", "mac" => $_);
    print $m->convert("bit_group" => 16, "delimiter", ".")
'
0123.4567.89ab
```

For arbitrary ASCII text, you could [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack) delimited pairs and then string-concatenate pairs of them back together:

```
$ echo 'bl:ab:la:bl:ab:la' | perl -MList::Util=pairmap -nE '
    say join ".", pairmap { $a . $b } unpack("(A2x)*",$_)
'
blab.labl.abla
```

Answer (score 4):

### Manipulating bash parameters

You can do it by manipulating bash parameters, remove the colons, then insert the dots between 4-character strings. See the chapter about 'Parameter Expansion' in `man bash` for details.

The following shellscript file `script` can do what you want,

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function converter {

 tmp0="$1"
 tmp1=${tmp0//:/}
 #echo "$tmp1"
 tmpstr="${tmp1:0:4}.${tmp1:4:4}.${tmp1:8:4}"
 echo "$tmpstr"
}

#######
# main
#######

if test -s "$1"
then
 while read line
 do
  converter "$line"
 done < "$1"
else
 echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <file-with-list-of-macs>"
fi
```

Example: I made a small input file `macs`

```
ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl
12:ab:34:cd:56:ef
qw:er:ty:as:df:gh
```

and run the following command,

```
$ ./script macs
abcd.efgh.ijkl
12ab.34cd.56ef
qwer.tyas.dfgh
```

### Command line with sed

You can also use `sed` doing almost the same as above: remove the colons, then insert the dots after 4-character strings, and finally you must remove the extra dot at the end of each line,

```
$ < macs sed -e 's/\://g' -e 's/..../&./g' -e 's/\.$//'
abcd.efgh.ijkl
12ab.34cd.56ef
qwer.tyas.dfgh
```

With a huge input file this solution with `sed` is significantly faster than the bash shellscript.

```
< huge.in sed -e 's/\://g' -e 's/..../&./g' -e 's/\.$//' > huge.out
```